# Geth node resyncs entire ledger after adding --rpc.gascap 0`

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a fully synced mainnet full node running Geth 1.10.6, and when I try to add `--rpc.gascap 0` into the startup command, it starts syncing from block 0, even though it has a fully synced ledger in the `datadir` that it can use.  I don't believe this was an issue before (1.10.2/3), but am seeing this after updating my nodes to Geth 1.10.6 this week.  With the London hardfork and EIP-1559 coming with 1.10.6, is this a new expected behavior from something that changing the `rpc.gascap` of a node impacts?

Here is my Geth cmd that I am using for this node.  The only thing I added that was different is the `--rpc.gascap 0` line.

```
geth \
  --syncmode "fast" \
  --gcmode "full" \
  --http \
  --http.addr 0.0.0.0 \
  --http.corsdomain "*" \
  --http.api eth,web3,net \
  --http.port "8545" \
  --http.vhosts '*' \
  --maxpeers "50" \
  --ws \
  --ws.addr 0.0.0.0 \
  --ws.origins "*" \
  --ws.port "8545" \
  --metrics \
  --pprof \
  --pprof.addr 0.0.0.0 \
  --pprof.port "6060" \
  --datadir /ethereum/ \
  --cache "4096" \
  --networkid "1" \
  --mainnet \
  --verbosity "4" \
  --snapshot=false
```

Comment: this can't be true. gas cap has nothing to do with consensus or block processing. your `geth` is probably doing snap mode syncing which is new in 1.10.6

Comment: show us the log files where it says that it is downloading blocks from 0

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue.  We have our Geth run command inside of a `configMap` that gets loaded by the pod.  I manually added the `--rpc.gascap 0` line to the configMap, and forgot to add a `\` after.  The following settings were being omitted from our startup command.  I think the one that was missing that was causing problems was not setting the `--datadir /ethereum/` since we load our ledger backup from a different container in the pod.  Leaving this question up here in case someone else runs into an issue with trying to set `--rpc.gascap` and needs to know a list of options that work with it.

```
      --metrics \
      --pprof \
      --pprof.addr 0.0.0.0 \
      --pprof.port "6060" \
      --datadir /ethereum/ \
      --cache "4096" \
      --networkid "1" \
      --mainnet \
      --verbosity "4" \
      --snapshot=false
```